# Debugging a linked-list

Tags: c, debugging, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to build a single linked list Library in C.
I have all the code down but there is a bug that I cannot find and it makes my program fail few tests.

To be more specific.

Whenever I try to remove a node which contains certain data my test fails.
The node is not removed and my message saying that "This data is not in the list" is printed.

Can someone please have a look over it and tel me what am I missing?

```
/* list_insertn: create a new node and insert it at the <n>th position,
    where the head is at position 1
   Parameters
   - node*: a pointer to the head of a linked list
   - char*: data to be stored in the new node
   - int: the position in which to insert the new node
   Return: a pointer to the head of the linked list */
node* list_insertn(node* list, char* input, int n){

    // Base case
    if(n <= 1){
        // Create the new node and allocate memory for it
        node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct s_node));

        // Insert new node
        newNode->next = list;

        // Allocate enough memory for the data input
        newNode->data = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(input) +1));

        // Place data in the node
        strcpy(newNode->data, input);
        return newNode;
    }

    //If we exceed list length append at the end
    if(list->next == NULL){
        list->next = list_insert_tail(NULL, input);
    }

    // Advance through the list if not at the specified position
    list->next = list_insertn(list->next, input, n-1);
    return list;
}

/* list_remove: remove the node containing specific data; if multiple nodes
    contain the data, remove the node nearest to the head
   Parameters
   - node*: a pointer to the head of a linked list
   - char*: data that, if found in one of the nodes in the list, indicates
      the node to remove (in the case of multiple nodes containing the data,
      remove the node nearest to the head)
   Return: a pointer to the head of the linked list */
node* list_remove(node* list, char* input){
    //As long as we have elemnts
    if(list != NULL){
        // We check to see if they have the same data
        if(list->data == input){
            // We remove the link
            node *newNextNode = list->next;

            // Remove the data
            free(list->data);

            // An remove the node itself when done
            free(list);
            return newNextNode;
        }
            //If it\'s not the correct data we move forward through the list
        else{
            // And check following nodes recursively
            list->next = list_remove(list->next, input);
            return list;
        }
    }
        // But if we reach the end of the list
    else{
        // We print a warning message
        printf("Specified data does not exist in any of the nodes");
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I have to remove parts of the code because of Academic security.
I will leave only the parts that had mistakes.

Comment: Where is the C code.

Comment: I tried to copy paste but it's too long

Comment: If it is too long perhaps learn debugging as people tend to like short bits of code here. Narrow down the problem and post it (along with a decent description of the problem)

Comment: `if(list->data == input){`  : use `strcmp` instead of `==`

Comment: would this be the right condition 'if(strcmp(list->data, input) == 0)'?
For some reason it send me in an infinite loop...

Comment: @AdrianChiriac - Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes! it send me into an infinite loop.

Comment: Why not try using the debugger?

Comment: I am stepping through but I haven't seen what's wrong yet...

Comment: One thing is for sure: The     'if(list->data == input)' fails but when I replace that with the strmcmp I get infinite loop. Still trying to understand why.

Comment: One thing you should do right away is replace all of the `\\n` with `\n`.  The former will literally come out as `\ ` followed by `n`, while the latter will be the newline that you presumably intended.

Comment: at `list_insert_tail` `if(list == NULL){` block, `list->next` isn't initialize to `NULL`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I think that is the problem.

Comment: list_insert_tail and list_print test:
one
two
three

list_insert_head and list_print test:
zero
one
two
three

list_remove test (middle):
zero
two
three

list_remove test (tail):
zero
two

list_remove test (head):
two

list_insertn test:
zero
one
two
three
three
two
three
three
two
three
three
two
three

Comment: I was stepping through it and that's where it broke...

Comment: Several runs and it works perfectly. Thank you very much!
And I also understand why it would broke which is great.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've debugged this for you.  Fixes:

1. In `list_insertn`, replace the entire `if` statement after the `"If we exceed list length append at the end"` comment with:

   ```
   if(list == NULL){
       return list_insert_tail(list, input);
   }
   ```
2. In `list_remove`, replace the test after the `"We check to see if they have the same data"` comment with:

   ```
   if(strcmp(list->data, input) == 0){
   ```
3. As general clean-up, fix all of the `\\n` instances to be just `\n`, and also add any missing `\n` characters to the end of your various `printf` format strings that need them.

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit number 1? I am not sure I fully understand why I was wrong.

Comment: The main case where this will make a difference is if `list` is `NULL`, which in the original version would cause a segmentation violation/core dump.  It's also cleaner to just map the entire case onto the existing `list_insert_tail` logic rather than to do something different, but you could of course pass `NULL` as the first argument to `list_insert_tail`.

Comment: Yes, the return was missing as well.  And it failed if `list` was `NULL`.

Comment: No problem!  And I'm glad to see you're taking the time to understand the changes!